# Would like to retrieve RGB pixel values from another method but couldn't retrieve it

Tags: java, arrays, rgb

I'm still new to Java. I'm having trouble while retrieving the RGB pixel values from my method, compareHexaRGB which in this method I could get the difference pixel values based on comparison of 2 similar images. I tried the printString2DArray method but it doesn't work. It stated either incompatible types: String[][] cannot be converted to String[] or produce errors such as [[Ljava.lang.String;@6d09a8df

After I get the values, I would like to combine it to one Hex value then convert it to ASCII characters. I couldn't proceed to this process as the retrieve value couldn't work.

Here is the code for compareHexaRGB() method:

```
public class compareHexaRGB
{
 private static int w;
 private static int h;
 private static BufferedImage img;
 private static BufferedImage img2;
 private static String[][] check_hex2;
 private static String[][] check_hex4;
 private static String[][] message;

 public static void compareHexaRGB(BufferedImage image, BufferedImage image2, int width, int height) throws IOException
{
w = width;
h = height;
img = image;
img2 = image2;

}

public void check() throws IOException
{
    getPixelRGB1 pixel = new getPixelRGB1();
    getPixelData1 newPD = new getPixelData1();

    int[] rgb;
    int count = 0;

    int[][] pixelData = new int[w * h][3];
    check_hex2 = new String[w][h];
    check_hex4 = new String[w][h];

    for(int i = 0; i < w; i++) 
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < h; j++)
        {
            rgb = newPD.getPixelData(img, i, j);

            for(int k = 0; k < rgb.length; k++)
            {
                pixelData[count][k] = rgb[k];
            }

                if(pixel.display_imgHex2()[i][j].equals(pixel.display_img2Hex2()[i][j]))
                {
                    System.out.println("\nPixel values at position 2 are the same." + "\n" + pixel.display_imgHex2()[i][j] + "  " + pixel.display_img2Hex2()[i][j]);
                }
                if(pixel.display_imgHex4()[i][j].equals(pixel.display_img2Hex4()[i][j]))
                {
                    System.out.println("\nPixel values at position 4 are the same." + "\n" + pixel.display_imgHex4()[i][j] + "  " + pixel.display_img2Hex4()[i][j]);
                }
                if(!pixel.display_imgHex2()[i][j].equals(pixel.display_img2Hex2()[i][j]))
                {
                    System.out.println("\nPixel values at position 2 are not the same." + "\n" + pixel.display_imgHex2()[i][j] + "  " + pixel.display_img2Hex2()[i][j]);
                    check_hex2[i][j] = pixel.display_img2Hex2()[i][j];
                    System.out.println("\nOutput Hex 2: " + check_hex2[i][j]);
                }
                if(!pixel.display_imgHex4()[i][j].equals(pixel.display_img2Hex4()[i][j]))
                {
                    System.out.println("\nPixel values at position 4 are not the same." + "\n" + pixel.display_imgHex4()[i][j] + "  " + pixel.display_img2Hex4()[i][j]);
                    check_hex4[i][j] = pixel.display_img2Hex4()[i][j];
                    System.out.println("\nOutput Hex 4: " + check_hex4[i][j]);
                }
                if(!pixel.display_imgHex2()[i][j].equals(pixel.display_img2Hex2()[i][j]) || (!pixel.display_imgHex4()[i][j].equals(pixel.display_img2Hex4()[i][j])))
                {
                    System.out.println("\nOne of the pixel values at position 2 and 4 are not the same." + "\n" + pixel.display_imgHex2()[i][j] + "  " + pixel.display_img2Hex2()[i][j] + "\n" + pixel.display_imgHex4()[i][j] + "  " + pixel.display_img2Hex4()[i][j]);

                    if(!pixel.display_imgHex2()[i][j].equals(pixel.display_img2Hex2()[i][j]) || (pixel.display_imgHex2()[i][j].equals(pixel.display_img2Hex2()[i][j])))
                    {
                        check_hex2[i][j] = pixel.display_img2Hex2()[i][j];
                        System.out.println("\nOutput Hex 2: " + check_hex2[i][j]);
                    }

                    if(!pixel.display_imgHex4()[i][j].equals(pixel.display_img2Hex4()[i][j]) || (pixel.display_imgHex4()[i][j].equals(pixel.display_img2Hex4()[i][j])))
                    {
                        check_hex4[i][j] = pixel.display_img2Hex4()[i][j];
                        System.out.println("\nOutput Hex 4: " + check_hex4[i][j]);
                    }

                }
            count++;
            System.out.println("\nOutput Count: " + count);
        }

    }

}

public String[][] getCheck_hex2()
{
    return check_hex2;
}

public String[][] getCheck_hex4()
{
    return check_hex4;
}
}
```

Code for extractMessage() method:

```
public class extractMessage
{
private static String character;
private static String[][] char1;
private static String[][] char2;
private static int w;
private static int h;

public static void printString2DArray(String[][] inn) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < inn.length; i++) 
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < inn[i].length; j++)
        {
            if (i != 0 && j == 0)
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.println(inn[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

public static void charExtract()
{
compareHexaRGB hexRGB = new compareHexaRGB();

char1 = hexRGB.getCheck_hex2();

    System.out.println("Char 1: ");
    printString2DArray(char1);

}

public String convertHexToString()
{
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();

extractMessage extract = new extractMessage();
extract.charExtract();

for(int i = 0; i < extract.length(); i+=2) //error stated couldn't find symbol extract
{
String output = extract.substring(i, (i + 2));
int decimal = Integer.parseInt(output, 16);
sb.append((char)decimal);

temp.append(decimal);
}
return sb.toString();
}
}
```

Any help I would appreciate!

EDIT: I change the code now. The output produces as this.

```
Char 1: 
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
6
6
null
null
6
null
null
null
null
null
```

It shouldn't be output that way right? I don't want the null character but I only want the value. How should I do then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `printString2DArray` method should look like:

```
private static void printString2DArray(String[][] in)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < in.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < in[i].length; j++) {
            if (i != 0 && j == 0) {  // This is just formatting (you may want to change it)
                System.out.print(", ");
            }
            System.out.print(in[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

To iterate over the array `String[][]` you may use 2 indexes(`i` and `j`), since it is a 2-dimensional array.

**Edit:**

Instead of this:

```
char1 = new String[][]
{
new String[] { hexRGB.getCheck_hex2() } //error stated incompatible types
};
```

you could try:

```
char1 = hexRGB.getCheck_hex2();
```

Comment: I've done that but in my charExtract() still got error incompatible types: String[][] cannot be converted to String[]. public static void charExtract()
    {
    compareHexaRGB hexRGB = new compareHexaRGB();
    
    char1 = new String[][]
    {
        new String[] { hexRGB.getCheck_hex2() }
    };
    
    System.out.println("Char 1: ");
    printString2DArray(hexRGB.getCheck_hex2());
    
    } Can you check?

Comment: I've done that too but I still get the same error incompatible types. It shouldn't get that error right after changing the String[] to String[][]? hmm

Comment: No, are you sure the types of variables are the same with the type of the value you are assigning it? If `getCheck_hex2` returns a `String[][]`, `char1` should be of type `String[][]`. Check that on all your variables.

Comment: for getCheck_hex2 I declare it as String[][] getCheck_hex2(). I've tried several method now and the output turns out to be like this. Char 1: 
null
null
null
null
null
null
 null
 null
 6
 6
 null
 null
 6
 null
 null
 null
 null
 null